# Recurring over Pandas rows line by line

Tags: python, loops, rows

I am seriously stuck for days on the following problem and would appreciate some help as I am new to Python. I am trying to iterate over a DataFrame by using Broadcasting instead of using a For Loop (that takes 20 minutes over 90k lines), here is the Dataframe sample:

[DataFrame Sample click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbDU7.png)

(Please note that BLong should be ALL '1's from 0.7296 up, but apparently Python iterates just "1 time over each command"

```
x['BBuyPx']= np.where((x['BReg1'] + x['BReg2'].shift(-1) == 2) & (x['BLong'].shift(-1) == 0), x['y'], 0.0)

x['BLong'] = np.where((x['BLong'].shift(-1) - x['BShort'].shift(-1)) == 1, 1, (np.where(x['BBuyPx'] != 0.0, 1, 0))).astype(int)

x['BShort'] = np.where(x['BLong'].shift(-1) == 0, 0, np.where(x['BSellPx'] != 0.0, 1, 0)).astype(int)

x['BSellPx'] = np.where(((x['BReg3'] + x['BReg2'].shift(-1) == 2) | (x['diff'] > sl)) & (x['BLong'].shift(-1) - x['BShort'].shift(-1) == 1), x['y'], 0.0)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us what problem you're trying to solve, and what issue you're having with your proposed solution?

Comment: I am trying to create a new panda column on a DF. Each row of this new column depends on the row immediately below. Using the formula below is not working as python does not recur over an over. I am trying to avoid a for() loop as it is 90k rows and takes 20 minutes. 

x['BLong'] = np.where((x['BLong'].shift(-1) - x['BShort'].shift(-1)) == 1, 1, (np.where(x['BBuyPx'] != 0.0, 1, 0))).astype(int)